# How to add translucency gradient to a square from top to bottom?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have no idea how to make an object translucent at the bottom but opaque at the top. My object is a 2D square.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SquareColorChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color startColor;
    public Color endColor;

    private Image _image;

    private void Start()
    {
        _image = GetComponent<Image>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float lerpValue = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); // this could be replaced with any other value that goes from 0 to 1
        _image.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, lerpValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lerping a color would change it over time. An image has only one `Color` value.
For what you want to to you either need to either put a gradient texture in the alpha channel which would be the easiest solution for this or create your own shader.
[How to create gradient in shader graph](https://abbabon.github.io/2020-07-22-shader-graph-gradient/) you could follow this and make sure to put your gradient into alpha channel.